# Change language properties 7z sfx self extracting .exe with 7zSFX Builder

Tags: windows, executable, zip

I use the [7zSFX Builder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s-zipsfxbuilder/) program to build my executable .exe from a .7z and even though I always select English in the settings (and everything else), the properties of the executable show Russian.

[image]

7zSFX Builder was abandoned and is no longer supported, so I will not get a response from the creator or the forum. So i tried with [7zSFX Constructor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sfxconstructor/), [7-ZIP SFX Maker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sfx-maker/), and [Make SFX](https://revocue.cz/en/make-sfx/index.php), but they don't allow adding or editing information to the executable's properties.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34474777/8747573) it say using [Resource hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). But the problem with this editor (no updates since 2020) is that it does not work for files larger than 1 GB (System Error. Code: 8). I tried with [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/), but this editor corrupts files of that size. I managed to change the language only with the [Resource Turner](http://www.heaventools.com/download-resource-editor.htm)

To avoid using 3rd party programs, is there any way to fix 7zSFX Builder issue, so that I can build my .exe with the English language? Thanks